# Java - JOptionPane.showInputDialog errors

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, joptionpane

Hello all I am experiencing issues with my `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` input field.
The issue i am experiencing that is when the cancel button is selected or the OK button is selected with empty or with categorical i am greeted with an error. Any suggestions.
My first attempt at fixing this i changed the c int into an interger therefore i could use an if statement along with null such as

```
Integer cInterger = new Integer(c);
  if (cInterger.equals(null)){
      return;}
```

Along with

```
cInterger == null
cInterger !=null
```

But to no avail

```
int a = 0;  //
int b = 0; //
int c = 0; //
    if (selected) {
        if (command.equals("amount")) { 
            Scanner readFile = null;
                try {
                    readFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("BANK.txt"));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    String account = "";
                    account = readFile.nextLine(); 
                    String amount = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Enter an amount"); //assign user input to string amount
                    a= Integer.parseInt(account); //conversion of scanned string to int for easy subtraction                
                    b= Integer.parseInt(amount); 
                    c = a-b; 

                        try {  
                                if( c == 0){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Granted.","Granted",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);}
                                else if (c > 0){
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Granted.","Granted",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); }
                                else{
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Denied.","Denied",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
```

Resulting errors

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at Options$1MyItemListener.itemStateChanged(Options.java:58)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.itemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setSelected(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.ButtonGroup.setSelected(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setSelected(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)), you will find that

> Returns: 
> user's input, or **null** meaning the user canceled the input

So attempting to parse `null` makes no sense, instead you should be using something like...

```
if (amount != null) {
    a = Integer.parseInt(amount);
    //...
```

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` seems reasonably obvious.

```
if (amount != null) {
   if (amount.trim().length() > 0) {
       //...
   } else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The amount you entered is invalid");
   }
```

You should also check the `account` value as well

Comment: I tried this but I still receive a long list of errors

Comment: Like what......? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: now the error is at null. would it be `if (account != null) {
   if (account.trim().length() > 0) {
       //...
   } else {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "The amount you entered is invalid");
   }` due to account being the string linked with the input? I apologize if I sound stupid its 2am where I am

Comment: I assume when nothing is entered into the input

Comment: So you need to validate both the `amount` AND `account` values.  Personally, I'd validate the `account` and not ask for the `amount` until it's right...